# Solving 'simple' system of linear equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, problem-solving

I want to solve the following system of equations where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is arbitrary

$$ax+12y=(a+16)x$$
$$12x+(a+7)y = (a+16)y$$

I know that a solution is $x = a$ and $y = \frac{4}{3}a$ but how do I derive this?

Comment: Is there a mistake as $a$ disappears from the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By distributing and moving over to the left side of the equal sign, the first equation is equivalent to

$$-16x+12y=0 \iff 4x-3y=0$$

The second is equivalent to

$$12x-9y=0\iff 4x-3y=0$$

So having the second equation introduces no new information. When this happens the system is *dependent*, i.e. possesses infinitely many solutions.

You can *choose* to let $x=t$ be an arbitrary value, and by substituting this into either equation, you find $y=\dfrac{4}{3}t$.

The solution you gave:  $x=a, y=\dfrac{4}{3}a$ is a *particular solution* to this system, if we let $t=a$, but it's just one of an infinite number. For example, $(x,y)=(3,4)$ is a solution, as is $(0,0)$ and $(6a^3, 8a^3)$.

Comment: Helped alot. I will accept this answer when permitted. Any idea why a numerical solver yields the constant $a$ in the particular solution?

Comment: Either it defaults to paremeterizing by the letter $a$ instead of $t$ or just because numerical solvers can't think abstractly.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:  The first equation implies
$$
ax + 12 y = ax +16 x \quad \Rightarrow \quad 12 y = 16x \quad \Rightarrow \quad y = \frac{4}{3} x.
$$
Plug this equation into the second equation and solve for $x$.